# How can I get list of nested objects on server side using? One to many relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a next architecture:
2 entity classes, relation one to many.
One auto service and many services for it.
Right now I want to get all services for one auto service by name.

Can I even do it ? Or should I send on client full Object and get the list after ?

I have 2 Entities with all getters and setters. I won't post them for saving space.

My AutoService.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AutoRate")
public class AutoService {

    public AutoService() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "serviceName", nullable = false)
    private String serviceName;

    @Column(name = "imageURL", nullable = false)
    private String imageURL;

    @Column(name = "mapCoordinate", nullable = false)
    private String mapCoordinate;

    @Column(name = "websiteURL", nullable = false)
    private String websiteURL;

    @Column(name = "phoneNumber", nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autoService", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Service> services = new ArrayList<Service>();
}
```

Service.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Service")
public class Service {

    public Service() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "serviceId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long serviceId;

    @Column(name = "serviceName", nullable = false)
    private String serviceName;

    @Column(name = "category", nullable = false)
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private int price;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "autoServiceId", nullable = false)
    private AutoService autoService;
}
```

I have next Repository interface:

```
public interface AutoRateRepository extends JpaRepository<AutoService, Long> {
    AutoService findByServiceName(String serviceName);
    List<Service> findServicesByServiceName(String serviceName);
}
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class AutoRateServiceImpl implements AutoRateService {
 @Override
    public List<com.webserverconfig.user.entity.Service> getAllServicesByAutoServiceName(String name) {
        return repository.findServicesByServiceName(name);
    }
}
```

And method from my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getServices/{serviceName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Service> getServices(@PathVariable("serviceName") String serviceName){
        List<Service> services = dataBaseService.getAllServicesByAutoServiceName(serviceName);
        return services;
    }
```

Structure from database:
[image]

Current error when I am trying to get list of services:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.webserverconfig.user.entity.AutoService] to type [com.webserverconfig.user.entity.Service]] with root cause
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.webserverconfig.user.entity.AutoService] to type [com.webserverconfig.user.entity.Service]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend mixing queries that produce different entities(others than the one specified in `JpaRepository<E,I>`interface generic types).

I would create a separate repository just for the `Service` entity queries and put that method inside there:

```
public interface ServiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Service, Long> {
    List<Service> findByServiceName(String serviceName);
}
```

The problem with your current approach is that Spring will always try to cast the result to the type specified in the generic params of `JpaRepository`.. which is `AutoService`.

Comment: Will I face with a problem in the future that framework cannot find services by autoservice name ? If iI'll move everything for service ?